# findOrCreate in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, eloquent

I want to create data but if the data already in database, it will update. but if the data not already in database, it will create new data.

**this my controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $real = SpentTime::findOrCreate([
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason')
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'reals'));
}
```

**this my model**

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id)
{
    $real = SpentTime::find($plan_id);
    return $real ?: new SpentTime;
}
```

when I make data already in the database, the data is not updated.

Comment: Use `updateOrCreate()`: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
$user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => Input::get('name')));
$user->foo = Input::get('foo');
$user->save()
```

Comment: in my controller ?

Comment: @NaKoriah yes you need to add this in your controller

Comment: nothing change. nothing to updated

Comment: this is laravel internal function you can read this here `https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models` and find this `firstOrCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $real = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'),[
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason')
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'reals'));
}

public static function findOrCreate($plan_id,$data)
{
    $real = static::where('plan_id',$plan_id)->first();
    if (is_null($real)) {
        return static::create($data);
    } else {
        return $real->update($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: error [errors](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vssiRY-vaW8/W72WZL-8OcI/AAAAAAAAA4I/zsSHX281kQkeRCzQqAkdtGalSaRHJU4PACLcBGAs/s1600/Capture.JPG)

Comment: @NaKoriah check i updated my answer

Comment: what is wrong ? https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7TLnRJtLOwo/W72aKhRlP9I/AAAAAAAAA4U/ZVGbfYFgT7MlApT4iTwJvImabANm6fyzwCLcBGAs/s1600/Capture.JPG

Comment: @NaKoriah again u try

Comment: the error is `Undefined variable: record`

Comment: it works. thanks a lot sir. just change the `$record` to `$real`

Comment: @NaKoriah welcome